# BIDS Import from changing file name [wildcard?]

Tags: variables, bids

I'm attempting to create a process to import data. I created the entire process and it works, but I'm having trouble creating the variable to find the file name of the csv i want to import automatically. Each time a new csv is uploaded to me it has a timestamp on it. I want to be able to grab that file no matter what the name is and do work to it.

So for example this week the file name would be

```
filename_4-14-2014.csv
```

And next week

```
filename_4_21_2014.csv
```

And so on into eternity. . .

Is there a way to create a variable that picks up the full file name even though its changing?

Comment: I've come to find that the import process in BIDS is very specific.  I would suggest creating a batch file that searches out the new CSV and renames it, or copies the contents to one you know exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so to accomplish what I wanted I created a Foreach Loop Container. Using the foreach loop container I had it look for any files ending with .csv in my specified folder by using a wildcard [denoted by asterisk: *.csv] .

Within the Foreach Loop container is as follows.

```
Step 1: File System Task - rename file. 
Step 2: Data Flow Task - Import data to sql
Step 3: File System Task - Copy the file to another folder, append datetime to filename
Step 4: File System Task - Delete source file.
```

I used variables to get all the file and folder names plus datetimes.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some poking around, I've discovered the following...

You can use a file system task to perform the copy operation I was referring to.  You can set the input file and the output file as variables.  This way you can always know that the file you use for import is always named the same, and has the right data.

You just need to add the variables and a File System Task to your package.

Comment: OK. Do you know how I can get the name of my original file to rename it at the start of the process? So if it's named File_14-14-2014.csv, grab it, name it file.csv and then the rest of the process can run.

Comment: If you know that the file name will contain a date, you can write that into another variable string when you are generating the name.

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out?

Comment: I was. I'm going to post my answer separately. I was on vacation so I'll do that now.

Comment: Okay.  So you accepted my answer, but rewrote your own, in your own words, and took credit for it?  Or did I miss something here?

Comment: I upvoted you for helping but the real magic was the foreach loop container which is where the wildcard lives.